# Unable to grant file permission using exec-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I'm trying to grant file permission using next exec-maven-plugin config:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>grant-permissions</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>chmod</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>+x</argument>
                            <argument>${somePath}/*.sh</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

It prints

> chmod: cannot access
>   ‘...my_path.../*.sh’:
>   No such file or directory

But when I replace

```
<argument>${somePath}/*.sh</argument>
```

by `<argument>${somePath}/myfirst_script.sh</argument>` 
- all works fine!

Could you please clarify how to use such approach and make argument more general using "*.sh"?

**EDIT**:

Initially I need this since I use dependency-plugin to unpack my dependency, but for some reason it looses file permissions, it seems related JIRA is -https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEP-109

I know that there is antrun approach to return permissions back, but actually it looks ugly, I want to avoid using antrun plugin in my pom.xml...

Comment: Where is `${somePath}` located?

Comment: @khmarbaise it is in 'home' directory. also please take a look at my update

Comment: So you have a script which is located in home folder and not within the module where you are running the build (exec-maven-plugin) and you are astonished that this does not work? In my opinion this is as expected, cause you have to define the path to the script. Or i misunderstand your question.